# Mock Kinect for Unit Testing with official SDK

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

As the title suggest, I want to know how can I mock the Kinect sensor so that I can run unit tests. Using the Kinect SDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the headers files in the Kinect SDK 1.8. So if you make corresponding *.cpp files and compile them into a library, you should have a mock kinect.

But it will probably take a lot of work and the question is if there's enough information available on the functions and response to be able to do this.

An easier way to go could be to use Kinect Studio to record for some time and to play this recorded data during your unit test.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855389.aspx